# Run process and wait for it AND its child processes to end

Tags: c, windows, process

I need to make a small program that runs an exe file and then waits for it and all its child processes to end.

The order of events is:

1. Process **A** runs program **B** and waits for it to finish
2. **B** launches another program, **C**
3. **B** does not wait for **C** to finish, and simply exits
4. How can process **A** wait for **C**?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: maybe I should mention that I have no control over the code of programs B and C, only A.

Comment: I've seen this before here on SO, but it was some time ago. Can't seem to find the duplicate though.

Comment: The title somehow does not really reflect the question. Please clarify.

Comment: The magic phrase in MSDN is "job object".

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any duplicate